# Have 37% of those arrested for antisemitism in Germany been Jews?

Tags: germany, jews, antisemitism

I saw the image below circulating on Facebook.

[image]

There's also [a Tweet](https://twitter.com/quendergeer/status/1759550714978631839) with 48K likes repeating the claim.

> germany's jews represent 1% of its population, but 37% of those arrested for antisemitic offences since Oct 7th

Can anyone provide a source for the claim that Jews comprise "37% of those arrested for antisemitic offenses since Oct 7th"?

Comment: How is that sign anti-semitic?

Comment: Can you please provide a source for the 37% claim, I'm not sure that is notable. The specific arrest quoted there is notable, but that is not your actual question.

Comment: @JRE I wonder if they interpreted that Palestine-coloured Star of David to mean that Israel should be consumed into Palestine and cease to exist. Denying Israel's right to existence is often held to be anti-semitic. Whether that was the protestor's intention, I can't say.

Comment: [This Instagram post](https://www.instagram.com/mudiblick/reel/C3f6bGPMMOo/) appears to be from the same scene as the picture.  The video shows the woman taken aside by the police, carrying her placard.  Immediately afterwards, she is shown again still with the placard but no longer accompanied by the police.

Comment: @JRE To me this video looks like the police took her aside, talked to her and then let her go. The caption describes this as 'brutally arrested' although the video shows neither brutality nor an arrest.

Comment: @quarague:  That's what it looked like to me as well.  No arrest, and if the placard had been truly been a problem they wouldn't have let her take it with her afterwards.

Comment: You can hear the [audio of the video here.](https://www.instagram.com/reels/audio/408328225200004/)  It seems to match the text from the video.